# AttributeError: object has no attribute when adding new class variables

Tags: attributeerror

I have the following CODE (Snippets)...  It might be useful for others... but I have one Problem...  One of my class variables seems to not work, as if there is a limit to the number of variables you can use?

```
    import csv

    class MASAT_data:
    #
    #  ALL CSV files are expected to have the first row as headers
    #  ALL CSV files are expected to have the first column as the key attribute
    #  All Headers are extracted into its own object variable
    #

    def __init__(self, fname, action, intest):
        __data_Dict = {}
        __fname = fname
        __header = []             # <--- THIS WORKS
        __colLEN = 0
        __rowLEN = 0
        __data_rows = []          # <--- This seems to not be available to the class
        #__test = intest
        if action.upper == "NEW":
            pass
        else:
            self.Get_DICT(__fname)
    def Get_DICT(self,filename):
        templist = []
        daDict = {}
        with open(filename,"r") as f:
            csv_f = csv.reader(f)
            x=-1
            for row in csv_f:
                x+=1
                if len(row)!=0:
                    if x == 0:
                        self.__header = row
                        self.__colLEN = len(self.__header)
                    else:
                        templist = row
                        self.__data_rows.append(templist)   # <-- line 38
                        if len(templist) >= 2:
                            daDict[templist[0]] = templist[1:]
        self.__rowLEN = x
        f.close()
        self.__data_Dict = daDict
    def rtnData(self,keyName):
        return self.__data_Dict[keyName]
    def hlen(self):
        return self.__colLEN
    def __len__(self):
        return self.__rowLEN
    def rtnList(self):
        templist = [[]]
        temps = []
        for key, value in self.__data_Dict.items():
            temps.append(key)
            for x in value:
                temps.append(x)
            templist.append(temps)
            temps = []
        templist.pop(0)


        #for x in range(len(templist)):
        #    print(templist[int(x)])
        return templist
    def rtnListDict(self):
        templist = []
        for x in range(len(self.__header)):
            print (self.__header[x])
            #print (self.__data_Dict[self.__header[x]])
```

I get the following ERROR:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/MASAT-3/MA-SAT_v3_MAIN.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/MASAT-3/MA-SAT_v3_MAIN.py", line 10, in <module>
    appCONFIGs = MASAT_data("CONFIG.csv","LOAD",t)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\MASAT-3\MASAT_Libs.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.Get_DICT(__fname)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\MASAT-3\MASAT_Libs.py", line 38, in Get_DICT
    self.__data_rows.append(templist)
AttributeError: 'MASAT_data' object has no attribute '_MASAT_data__data_rows'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

The calling program is as follows:

```
    __author__ = 'User'
    import sys
    from MASAT_Libs import *

    sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\MASAT-3')
    t = 0
    #define Globals

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        appCONFIGs = MASAT_data("CONFIG.csv","LOAD",t)
        if appCONFIGs.rtnData("ApplicationMode")[0] == 'DEBUG':
            t = 1
        else:
            t = 0
        print("t = ",t)
        observations = MASAT_data(appCONFIGs.rtnData("PathName")[0] + "\\Observables.csv", "LOAD",t)
        KMNs = MASAT_data(appCONFIGs.rtnData("PathName")[0] + "\\KMN_List.csv", "LOAD",t)
        geomix = MASAT_data(appCONFIGs.rtnData("PathName")[0] + "\\geomix_perf_list.csv", "LOAD",t)

        print (geomix.rtnList())
        print (len(geomix))

        geomix.rtnListDict()
```

So please forgive me if I put in a extra space, or didn't indent correctly (I did it manually when coping the code here...

My problem is that I can't add another variable to this class (no matter what the name) without it crassing in this manner.  Any ideas for a simple fix?

Comment: O, yes, forgot to say,  when I delete the 2 lines (the declaration in the __init__ function, and the one on line 38... all is fine...

Answer (score 0):

the proper ways to declare instance variables are:

```py
class MASAT_data:
    def __init__(self, some_var):
        # like this
        self.__header = []
        self.__data_rows = []
        self.__some_var = some_var

    def some_func(self):
        # and referenced like this
        self.__header.append(['test'])
        self.__data_rows.append(['test'])
        print(self.__some_var)
```

When you declare a variable in `__init__`, its scope is limited to `__init__`. so if you need to reference it elsewhere, it must have a bigger scope. hence `self.your_var = []`

Comment: so its not a static for all instances of that class?  And, why does the other ones work?

Comment: Well, the errors are gone, but now all instances of this class are contained in these variables.  I need them to be instance only, they seem to be static when in this location.

Comment: The variables declared as class attributes can be accessed both as `static` and instance. In these cases they'd have different values. If you refer to them as `MASAT_data.__header` you'd get the `static` value. If you refer to them like this: 
`m = MASAT_data()`
`m.__header` you'd get the instance value.

Comment: as to your question about why others work, you are actually not referring to the variable you declared in `__init__` instead you are dynamically initializing a new instance variable by doing `self.__header = row` on line 34. its like doing `self.__header = []`. As for line 38, `self.__data_rows.append(...` `self.__data_rows` does not exist as of yet unless you have done `self.__data_rows = []` before somewhere in the code. So it throws an error when you try to call a non-existent function `.append()` of an unknown variable.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this seems to have worked I was playing around a bit...  All I really had to do is put `self.`  infront of all the variables...  Not sure why but this seems to be needed??  If anyone knows why that is the case, I'd love to know the technical reasons...

```
def __init__(self, fname, action, intest):
    self.__data_Dict = {}
    self.__fname = fname
    self.__header = []             # <--- THIS WORKS
    self.__colLEN = 0
    self.__rowLEN = 0
    self.__data_rows = []          # <--- This seems to not be available to the class
    #__test = intest
    if action.upper == "NEW":
        pass
    else:
        self.Get_DICT(self.__fname)
```

Comment: You need to prefix `self.` because otherwise they'd just be local variables inside a function and they would cease to exist once the function has finished executing. By prefixing `self.` you are dynamically adding attributes to the class instance, and therefore they persist until the class instance remains in memory.